# Orchard CMS 1.7 Custom Theme images not loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I had started creating a new theme while using v1.6.1.

Things were not going well with a custom module creation so I decided to start from scratch. This time I am using the source from V1.7

I copied my custom theme folder, pasted it into the themes folder of the new 1.7 project and ran the site. I could see the theme in my dashboard so I set it to the current theme.

Now when I view my site NONE of the images are loading. The style sheets are loading, though none of the images - either from the style sheet or from any views - are loading.

My images are in myTheme/content/images - which as I understand it is how 1.6.1 required things to be laid out.

My content folder has a web.config as does my images folder. It's the same config used in 1.6.1 so I'm wondering if something has changed.

In one of my theme views I have the following code - this worked in 1.6.1:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme,"/Content/Images/phoneBullet.png"))" alt="T:" />
```

If I output this to my front-end I get:

```
~/Themes/PerformanceAbrasives/Content/Images/phoneBullet.png
```

This tells me things appear to be in the correct place - though I'm wondering if my web.config is now out of date?

I have this - there is a copy in content and a copy in images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- iis6 - for any request in this location, return via managed static file handler -->
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>

    <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
      <!--
      iis7 - for any request to a file exists on disk, return it via native http module.
      accessPolicy 'Script' is to allow for a managed 404 page.
      -->
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any pointers?

**UPDATE**

Ok... so if I set my project to use Visual Studios internal development server then all is well - if I tell it to use Local IIS Web server - use IIS Express (`http://localhost:30333/`) - then it doesn't work...

**UPDATE 2**

Ok - now running from IIS 7 and images do not load... stylesheets seem ok, but images are not.. grrr

any ideas so I don't run into this problem when I deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - I figured it....

You only need the web.config in my `Content` directory - not in both `content` AND `images`